# Can I trust that LyncReader is a valid Microsoft application

Tags: lync

I can not find any match on google searching for "LyncReader" from Microsoft.
I have an application I got from someone.  The name is "LyncReader.exe" created by Microsoft.
It reads Lync history which is a functionality I need, but is this a safe application?  Is it a Microsoft application?

Thanks for answers.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the application from? Is it signed?

Comment: I have got it from a friend.
No it is not signed.

Comment: If it's not signed, and it claims to be from Microsoft, but it wasn't aquired directly from them, I'd be very wary of it

Comment: Yes, that's why I am checking it up.
I find it strange that I do not get any match on google search.
But if it comes from Microsoft  I really want to use it.

Comment: I'd also be suspicious of the version numbers

Answer (score 2):

Since the .exe has no digital signature, you cannot be sure if this is something from MS. Even if it was, it could be tampered